# iframe messaging

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

как обмениваться сообщениями между iframe и родителем, кроме как postMessage. Почему не postMessage, потому что необходимо обмениваться не только переменными, но и передавать функции без преобразование к JSON, к примеру есть следующее,

```
let someConfig = {
    let someData = 'someVar';
    someFunction() {....}
    ........................
}
```

чтобы эти данные передавались в дочерний фрейм, и да дочерний фрейм находится в другом домене

Answer (score 0):

> но и передавать функции без преобразование к JSON

думаю предполагалось передавать объекты с переменными, функциями..

посмотрите вот это

[Object.prototype.toSource()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource)

пролистайте вниз, выдохните, "расслабьтесь и получайте удовольствие".

---

если я ошибся в своём предположении:

однако никто не запрещает делать так

```
function conteiner() {
    return new class CL {
        constructor() {
            this['param1'] = 'some val'
            this['count'] = 4
            this['show'] = function () {
                for (var i = this['count']; i > 0; i--) {
                    console.log(i, this['param1'])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

let str = conteiner.toString()

let doIT = `
    let foo = ${str}
    let cl = foo()
    cl['show']()
`
//передаём строку doIT
//и исполняем
eval(doIT)
```

так же, рекомендую посмотреть эту [статью от 2009г](https://habrahabr.ru/post/67961/) и комментарии к ней.